# Azure Data Factory run New Job Cluster Mode Databricks Python Wheel

Tags: pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, prophet

We are trying to install the external libraries via Azure data factory. After that we are planning to execute our notebook. Inside the notebook we will be using many different libraries to achieve the business logic.

In the Azure data factory, there is the Append Libraries option from where is possible to install new runtime libraries to the job cluster.

Our linked service connects always to a NEW JOB CLUSTER but we are getting below error while execute the ADF pipelines.

> Run result unavailable: job failed with error message  Library
> installation failed for library due to user error for whl:
> "dbfs:/FileStore/jars/ephem-4.1.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl"
> . Error messages: Library installation attempted on the driver node of
> cluster 1226-023738-9cm6lm7d and failed. Please refer to the following
> error message to fix the library or contact Databricks support.
>
> Error Code: DRIVER_LIBRARY_INSTALLATION_FAILURE. 
> Error Message:
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> dbfs:/FileStore/jars/ephem-4.1.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

Comment: check in notebook with `%fs ls dbfs:/FileStore/jars/ephem-4.1.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl`

Comment: Hi, after i changed below like a path while append the lib in ADF

Comment: dbfs:/FileStore/jars/df76d488_76e2_4e8c_a339_6dfa6ab95473/ephem-4.1.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

Comment: dbfs:/FileStore/jars/f901765a_18a4_4708_97b1_d2d7bb1fee4b/setuptools_git-1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: dbfs:/FileStore/jars/ac1ebabc_336f_41e9_8d88_6cbc4eb26b70/LunarCalendar-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: again I run the pipelines, still i am getting issues as below like

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prophet'

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prophet' -- error

Comment: add prophet library as well...

Comment: i am not able to understand, we already add right in above i shared the pip install path?
you mean to say like this %pip install Prophet ?